# dynamically attached textarea throws Error#1009 - but similar labels and textinputs do not

Tags: actionscript-3

This code in my scene works perfectly fine with the comments:

```
import state;
import fl.controls.TextInput;
import fl.controls.TextArea;
import flash.events.TextEvent;

state.data.newNotice = new Object();
state.data.newNotice.title='';
state.data.newNotice.text='';

var noticeTitleInput:TextInput = new TextInput();
noticeTitleInput.width = noticeTitleEditor.width;
noticeTitleInput.height = noticeTitleEditor.height;
noticeTitleInput.text = '';
noticeTitleInput.setStyle("textFormat", state.data.fontFormat);
noticeTitleEditor.addChild(noticeTitleInput);

noticeTitleInput.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);

/*var noticeTextInput:TextArea = new TextArea();
noticeTextInput.wordWrap = true;
noticeTextInput.width = noticeEditor.width;
noticeTextInput.height = noticeEditor.height;
noticeTextInput.text = '';
noticeTextInput.setStyle("textFormat", state.data.fontFormat);
noticeEditor.addChild(noticeTextInput);

noticeTextInput.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);*/

function onInput(event:TextEvent):void {
    state.data.newNotice.title = noticeTitleInput.text;
//  state.data.newNotice.text = noticeTextInput.text;
}
```

Uncomment it though and the textarea throws an error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at fl.controls::TextArea/drawLayout()
    at fl.controls::TextArea/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/drawNow()
    at fl.controls::ScrollBar/draw()
    at fl.controls::UIScrollBar/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::LabelButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/drawNow()
    at fl.controls::ScrollBar/draw()
    at fl.controls::UIScrollBar/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::LabelButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground()
    at fl.controls::BaseButton/draw()
    at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

I don't understand why this is not working with a text area because, the same pattern was working for me with label and with textinput. What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you add **TextArea** component to Library? It looks like you imported the classes without actually adding the relevant components to the project's Library.

Comment: the one with the link to `fl.controls.TextArea` - yes, it is on my library.

Comment: I just poked around. At first it worked fine on clean test. Then I found out that if you delete *Component Assets/TextAreaSkins/TextArea_upSkin* from Library then you get the **drawLayout** #1009 error. I guess there are other things could be missing to produce other errors you get. I advise you to clean up the Library and re-import the controls' assets.

Comment: @Organis please repost this as answer. I don't know how I messed up textArea, since I only just dragged it to the stage once to see what it looked like. But that was it. Works fine on reimport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash components require 2 things: component classes **and** component graphics that is added to Library when you drag components from their panel. Some components require a number of additional assets so if they are not in Library for whatever reason (deleted by mistake or something) that could result in runtime errors and/or non-functional components.

Developer should always keep the Library organized!